# How to minify multiple HTML / CSS files at once?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, performance, minify

I know I can minify files and concatenate them one by one before production, but that sounds like a tedious way to do it.

Is there some way to minify all my files before pushing it to production?

I am using NodeJS, with JS, CSS, and html.

I found this not sure if there is a better way or the answer:
https://github.com/srod/node-minify

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your setup? Gulp / Brunch / CodeKit - all the build tools will allow you to do this.

Comment: I actually do not use any build tools, that is what I am new to, I just push to heroku from git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to setup a build-tool or task-runner / or both.

If you are using Node (you know JavaScript) - but you are new to build tools, you may want to start with [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). The website should walk you through it. Webpack is pretty complex. I use Brunch and Broccoli and sometimes - when I need an easy to use GUI, CodeKit. There are lots of options. Learn Gulp and then you'll be in a good spot to think about other ways and their positives and negatives. Good Luck! : )

Comment: I agree, Gulp will take away the tedious tasks and can also push to Heroku after completing a build. i recommend following a tutorial on how to use Gulp for a better idea. Here's a random link from a Google Search: https://julienrenaux.fr/2014/05/25/introduction-to-gulp-js-with-practical-examples/